# I have trouble loading data from multiple csv files or python code in powerbi

Tags: powerbi

I am using power bi for loading some data. The data is present in the data lake store, and python can load data and do some initial transforms on the data.
The problem is however that the data is located in multiple files as per ID (1 - 10000). It is not possible to load all the data in memory.
I am looking for some way to have a button or something similar that acts as a selector for these Ids and then loads the data for the selected ID using python script, hopefully by passing a parameter to the python script.

Comment: If your data is located in different files, just load all the different files single in Power BI and in the end union them in the query designer to get the final file (table). Then scedule the refresh and Power BI repeats this steps by every refresh.

Comment: @Strawberryshrub your solution works, however, I don't want to load all files due to memory restrictions, it is only possible to load the single file at a time.